# what does the ids parameter mean on openerp?

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I'm using openerp and i need to call a python method from a web module using javascript.

this is the method:

```
def get_data(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    _logger.info('ids es %r',ids);
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    data = {}
    data['ids'] = context.get('active_ids', [])
    data['model'] = context.get('active_model', 'ir.ui.menu')
    data['form'] = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['user_id',  'date_start',  'date_end'], context=context)[0]
    _logger.info('data es %r',data);
    _logger.info('data[form] es %r',data['form']);
    return data;
```

however i don't know how to call this method from javascript because i don't really know what the ids parameter should be, anyways this is how i call it (i get an error because i'm not sending the ids parameter)

```
data = reportModel.call('get_data',[],undefined,{});
```

so my question is, what is the ids parameter, how does it work and what should i send to this function from javascript in order to succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you will be able to call this from javascript at all as you will need to pass in a database cursor from the connection pool for the appropriate database and you may need to use the XMLRPC interface.

That said, these methods exist on an ORM model (or transient model) and the ids parameter is the standard OpenERP pattern of passing in the IDS of records in the model this method is on that you want to process.  So if this method is on the account invoice model, the IDS would be a list of ids in the account_invoice table that you want to process.

Note that you just have to have the argument, you don't have to have anything in it or use it.  For example, most form on_change methods ignore it as those methods have to cater for users keying new records that don't exist in the database.